# filter unwanted filed using aggregator in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this query and it worked

```
Job.aggregate([ 
     {$match: { created_by: userId }},
     {$lookup: {
     from: "users", 
     localField: "applicant._id", 
     foreignField: "_id", 
     as: "applicant" }},
     {$unwind: {
         path :'$applicant', 
         preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
       }
     }       
   ])
  .then(data=>{
    res.json({status:1, data})
  })
```

The problem is applicant field brought in the password which is bad. I can do manipulation in the callback, but is there anyway I can filter out that using mongodb's query?

I know I can do filtering in findOne like so

```
User.findOne({id: user_id, {password: 0, _v: 0}).exec()
```

Comment: Use `$project` to disable fields populating in output

Answer (score 0):

use `$project` to disable a field projection in result

```
Job.aggregate([ 
     {$match: { created_by: userId }},
     {$lookup: {
     from: "users", 
     localField: "applicant._id", 
     foreignField: "_id", 
     as: "applicant" }},
     {$unwind: {
         path :'$applicant', 
         preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
       }
     },
     {$project : {"applicant.password" : 0}}   // disable -> 0   
   ])
  .then(data=>{
    res.json({status:1, data})
  })
```